# Почему в TeX надо устанавливать языки?

Tags: tex

Если `TeX` использует `Unicode`, то зачем для использования определённых языков надо устанавливать дополнительные пакеты и почему они весят от 50 мегабайт до более чем гигабайта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Язык" с точки зрения TeX, это еще и шрифты в векторе (самая тяжелая часть), стили (для разных языков получается разное написание дат, частей документа, подписей к рисункам и таблицам), правила расстановки переносов, набора текстов  (особенно для китайского и арабской группы языков).

Comment: А что за вектор?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, это жаргон. Имеется ввиду векторные шрифты в формате adobe type-1 со всеми служебными файлами. На самом деле, сами векторные шрифты  занимают не так уж много места. Больше места отъедает система генерации шрифтов (очень много всяких служебных файлов) и сгенерированные растровые шрифты.